# Ember - How to deal with 2 models, in a single page, and with one model very slow to load?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Quite new to Ember, I'm building an app and encounter a difficult problem.

**MY SITUATION**

I have a single page, which should display a list of elements, named "containers", and inside each container, I want to display several "contents".

For now, here is a very simplified version of my JS code (just to give you an idea):

```
App.ContainersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('container');
    }
});
App.Container = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    contents: DS.hasMany('content')
});
App.Content = DS.Model.extend({
    [...]
});
```

I will pass on the template part, wich is not a problem here, it's quite classic.

So, **this code is working**, I have my list of containers, and a list of the propers contents for each of them.

**MY PROBLEM = "A WHITE SCREEN OF DEATH"**

Indeed, as I fetch my data from a server in JSON, for now, before Ember transitionning to my page, I have a wait the loading of all the data.

The problem is that, "containers" data is quite small and static, so my server can answer it in less than a second, but, for the "contents" part, it is very long (between 20 to 40 seconds), as my server needs to do a lot of work to recover these date from my DB.

It would be ok for me to wait this long if my page was already loaded (navigation + containers without the contents), but right now, I just have a white page during 30s with no idea except the console to know is everything is ok.

Of course, I could use a "loading bar" thanks to "beforeModel" in the Route, but I would very much prefer to have access at least to the UI.

**FOR YOU, WHAT COULD BE A GOOD SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM?**

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make content's async and fetch that after the fact so you can give a more responsive look and feel.

```
App.Container = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    contents: DS.hasMany('content', {async: true})
});
App.Content = DS.Model.extend({
    [...]
});
```

That means Ember Data will make a callback for that data when requested, and not expect it at the same time as the container data.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1045/edit

Additionally you can add a loading route in the resource above your `Containers` resource which could give feedback about how your fetching data.  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cerid/2/edit

Personally I like the async idea more though, show the fact that you have containers, but then show contents as loading/empty.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Actually, I've tried to specify "async" in the Model, with no impact. But in my opinion, it's mostly because of my server, that currently has to make all the job in one request. Maybe I'm using "async" wrong. What should my answer from the server look like with "async: true" for the content?

Comment: Yeah, changing it to async would require you to make a server change as well.  You'd need to make it only return the container information on that initial request.

Comment: In the example included above you'll see you can handle async a few different ways.  If you look at the first response (the call to colors) I respond with a list of ids for the `folors`.  Ember Data will create a url and call expecting the structure returned in the `/folors` mocked response.  Or you can just send down a `links` hash with a `contents` property telling it the url to use.  In that case, the response will still look the same, but Ember Data will use the url you provided.

Comment: That looks perfect ! I will be trying that as soon as possible and give you a feedback, but it seems that indeed, this is a great answer. Funny, I was really looking for something more or different on the client side, without thinking that just this "async" param could be enough with some modification on the server site.

Comment: Great, it's working! Thanks a lot for your big help. Just one point, I don't know why, but it's not working with the use of a component. I have a component to handle the display of my list of containers, which is working fine otherwise, but with you code, it just keeps saying "loading". But as soon as I put the same code right back into the template, it's working. If you have an idea, I would take it :). Anyway thanks again.

Comment: Can you toss up the component and template associated with it?